# How do I make DbProviderFactories for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I get the same error as the guy in http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/239.aspx but the thing is he uses SQLite and I use SQL Server 2008 and adding that code don't change anything for me I still get the

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

I am trying to get the MVC 3 account to work with my websites database and changed the connectionstring to my own in web.config

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the name of your connection string, it seems as if you may have specified an `Entity Framework` connection string.

If so, you need to add a SqlClient connection string, and change your providers to use the SqlClient connection string.

Comment: They already use my connectionstring connectionStringName="madsskipper_dk_dbEntities" which is to my MSSQL database